# Horizantal tableview cell scrolling iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I had an issue in one of the app with horizantal table view scrolling.I created tableview with custom tableviewcell, in the custom tableviewcell I created one more tableview with the tableviewcells and tableview header.I transformed the tableview and tableview cells but after rotation the I am unable to change the frame of table view.Here is the code what I used so far...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//self.ibTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 568.0f;
self.ibTableView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
self.ibTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
self.ibTableView.pagingEnabled=YES;
self.ibTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
SPCustomTableVIewCellTableViewCell *cell = (SPCustomTableVIewCellTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = (SPCustomTableVIewCellTableViewCell *)[SPCustomTableVIewCellTableViewCell loadFromNib];
}

[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
cell.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
return cell;}
```

SPCustomTableVIewCell.m

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

self.headerView = [HeaderTableView loadFromNib];
self.internalTableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;
// Initialization code}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

InternalCustomTableViewCell *cell = (InternalCustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = (InternalCustomTableViewCell *)[InternalCustomTableViewCell loadFromNib];
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
return cell; }
```

Please any help to resolve the issue to set the frame after transformation of table view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply animations to a UITableViewCell, you should use

`- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

I think it is a bad solution to do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.